# Using efficient files

Tags: python

Is there any way how can I read and write files without loading all content in buffer?

Comment: Please give us a complete complete example, preferably one that works.

Comment: your question is not unreasonable. but please provide some more information, some technical terms might be confusing to some and the word buffer has multiple meanings. so does the word load, and youe desires are important for answering your question.

Comment: i have to say i am surprised at how low this question is voted, its a very nice question, and there are some really nice answers, i think it could benefit from some more content and a few edits. but the question is also a very simple one. sometimes the biggest crutch is how to handle all the data in a file efficiently.

Comment: Your operating system might buffer (part of) the file as soon as you open it.

Answer (score 4):

file objects are iterable:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

Iterating over them yields 1 line at a time (and doesn't store the whole file in memory)

---

Writing files is just as easy:

```
with open(filename,'w') as f:
     for x in get_data():
         f.write(x)
```

Or you could use the `writelines` method passing in a generator.  e.g. `f.writelines(get_data())`

where `get_data` could be defined as:

```
def get_data():
    for i in xrange(200):
        yield '%d\n'%i
```

Comment: That's just a very simple [generator function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)...

Answer (score 3):

you can use [seek](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for to go to the part of the file you want read.

from the docs:

> To change the file object’s position, use f.seek(offset, from_what).
> The position is computed from adding offset to a reference point; the
> reference point is selected by the from_what argument. A from_what
> value of 0 measures from the beginning of the file, 1 uses the current
> file position, and 2 uses the end of the file as the reference point.
> from_what can be omitted and defaults to 0, using the beginning of the
> file as the reference point.

after seeking you can read either bytes, or lines, just as you would a file initially loaded as normal.

here is an example function:

```
def special_read_file(filename, location, length):
    file_handle = open(filename)
    file_handle.seek(location, 0)
    return file_handle.read(length)
```

location and length are in bytes. file_name would be the string of the locaiton of the file you want to read.

you can do some nice and interesting things with seek. using it to jump around in a file, so that you don't have to store the files contents locally, and it still lets you iterate through lines.

as some other answers already mention, iterating over a files lines using `with` and `for line in file` are good ways of keeping the content light on your system. but passing a file_handle around is much simpler and you dont have to keep opening and closing or reading parts of it, you can open a handle and then whenever you need that specific file, read from where you need it.

here, i wrote a generator function which can work just as you normally would, only you can specify what part of the file to start reading from.

```
def read_handle_from(file_handle, start_point):
    file_handle.seek(start_point, 0)
    for line in file_handle:
        yield line

my_file_handle = open(file_name)
for line in read_handle_from(my_file_handle, 2000):
    #do stuff
```

you can easily modify the function to limit the amount of lines read, or the amount of bytes read however you wanted.

its very easy to create functions and generators for yourself to use how you want, dont be afraid of making your own functions in python, not everything needs to be built in.

Comment: I would generally think of `seek` to be used in different situations than `for line in file`.  (there's only a small set of problems where they're use togeher makes sense).  Specifically I typically use `seek` more for `binary` files.  For ascii, you don't **usually** know where the start/end of the lines are, so you could `seek` to the middle of a line and get garbage data from that read.  Anyway, nice answer.  +1

Comment: @mgilson thank you, i know that this is probably not the primary function of seek, i personally have used it in this way but with a much more robust function which finds the nearest linebreaks so i can get samples from files at "about the 2000 bytes for 5 lines" or some other such nonsense. also, its faster to seek to a part in a file than to iterate say 100 lines and ignore them till you get to what you want. (also - a lot of "report" files have interesting content at the end. this way i can seek to the end of the file and read some lines from it.)

Comment: @InbarRose Personally, for those use cases, I tend to `mmap` the file

Comment: Completely agree.  seeking is *super*, and I wasn't saying your example was invalid, only atypical.  It seemed like it should be mentioned somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. For example, the following looks at a file one line at a time:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
```

This doesn't load the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 1):

File objects, are iterable, so you can do what takes your fancy with them.

For instance, to write every other line from input to output, use something like:

```
from itertools import islice
with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    every_other = islice(fin, None, None, 2)
    fout.writelines(every_other)
```

Comment: +1 -- I like itertools.islice -- though you may want to link to the docs so that OP's not like "What in the world are those `None` doing there?".